# Entries related to Users

Tags: entries, users, relations

I know this question has been asked a few times but no of the answers work.

I have a News channel with a Users field type as one of the layout fields.

I want to find all news entries related to user id X but the entries returned are wrong.

```
{# Get current member e.g URL /members/1/ #}
{% set currentMember = craft.users.id(craft.request.segment(2)).first() %}

{# Get current members news entries #}
{% set currentMemberNews = craft.entries.section("news").relatedTo(currentMember) %}
```

`currentMemberNews` contains all news. I just want the `currentMember` news.

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `{{ currentMember.email }}` prints what you expect it to?

Comment: Yes, the correct email address is printed out.

Comment: There are 7 news entries in the system with only 2 news entries tagged to the current member.  I get all 7 news entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be caused by a bad relation. Removing the relation and re-creating the relationship between the User and entries fixed the issue. Dunno what caused it but it was very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
{% set currentMemberNews = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo({
    targetElement: currentMember,
    field: 'yourFieldHandle',
}) %}
```

To specifically define the correct field and the fact that the member is on the target side of this relation?

Comment: You won by 8secs!

Comment: Great minds think alike ;)

Comment: yourFieldhandle - do you mean the Users field handle in my News Channel ?

Comment: You define the field in which the relationship was initialized. In this case, the User field in your news channel. The big question, however ... does it work?

Comment: Okay, I've tried the above and I still get my 7 entries. :(

Comment: Could you show me how you loop through your entries?

Comment: `{% set currentMemberNews = craft.entries.section("news").relatedTo({targetElement: currentMember,field: "genericRelatedMembers",}).status("live") %}
FOUND: {{ currentMemberNews | length }}
{% if currentMemberNews | length %}
{% for article in currentMemberNews %}{{ article.title}}<br>{% endfor %}{% endif %}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19313/discussion-between-sean-delaney-and-paul-verheul).